# Machine leaning OneHotEncoding in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-analysis, sklearn-pandas

I am new to machine learning `scikit-learn`. I was going through the documentation and tried `OneHotEncoder()` with some sample data. Can someone please explain what is happening from encoder.feature_indices_ and how i get the output of     Encoded_Vector as `[[ 0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  0.]]`. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
>>> from sklearn import preprocessing
>>> encoder = preprocessing.OneHotEncoder()
>>> encoder.fit([[0, 2, 1, 12], [1, 3, 5, 3], [2, 3, 2, 12], [1, 2, 4,3]])
    OneHotEncoder(categorical_features='all', dtype=<type 'numpy.float64'>,
   handle_unknown='error', n_values='auto', sparse=True)
>>> encoder.n_values_
array([ 3,  4,  6, 13])    
>>> encoder.feature_indices_
array([ 0,  3,  7, 13, 26])
>>> vector_encoded = encoder.transform([[2,3,5,3]]).toarray()
>>> print "\nEncoded_Vector =",vector_encoded
Encoded_Vector = [[ 0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  0.]]
>>>
```

My understanding so far is

Input

0 2 1 12

1 3 5 3

2 3 2 12

1 2 4 3

This is 4 columns/features and 4 rows. Each column has different number of unique entities. If i run:

```
enc.n_values_
```

It gives: array([ 3,  4,  6, 13])

So categories for each feature are:

feature 1 can take 3 values : 0 1 2

feature 2 can take 4 values : 0 1 2 3

feature 3 can take 6 values : 0 1 2 3 4 5

feature 4 can take 13 values : 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12

Answer (score 0):

Even though you said that your features can take a total of 3, 4, 6 or 13 values, the data example you provided (`[[0, 2, 1, 12], [1, 3, 5, 3], [2, 3, 2, 12], [1, 2, 4,3]]`) did not cover the complete variety of your data.

Your example basically says that:

- feature 1 can take 3 values (0,1,2)
- feature 2 can take 2 values (2,3)
- feature 3 can take 4 values (1,2,4,5)
- feature 4 can take 2 values (3,12)

This ends up with a total of 11 values. Thus, the output from the OneHotEncoding (`[[ 0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  0.]]`) has 11 values, and it can be split into 4 sections:

- [0. 0. 1.] is the encoding for feature 1
- [0. 1.] is the encoding for feature 2
- [0. 0. 0. 1.] is the encoding for feature 3
- [1. 0.] is the encoding for feature 4

The position of the "1." in the array will tell you the value of the variable (try to match the example before encoding and after encoding).